What does Nietzsche mean here?

One gets to love something, and one has hardly begun to love it
profoundly when the tyrant in us (which we are all too ready to call
our "higher self") says, "Sacrifice precisely that to me." And we
surrender it too - but that is cruelty to animals and being roasted
over a slow fire. What you are dealing with are problems of cruelty,
nothing more or less - does this give you gratification? I tell you
frankly that I have in myself too much of this "tragic" complexion to
be able not to curse it; my experiences, great and small, always
take the same course. What I desire most, then, is a high point from
which I can see the tragic problem lying beneath me. I would like to
take away from human existence some of its heartbreaking and cruel character. Yes, to be able to continue here, I would have to reveal to
you what I have never yet revealed to anyone - the task which
confronts me, my life's task. No, we may not speak of this. Or rather,
being as we are, two very different persons, we may not even be silent
together on this point.

This is taken from the letter Nietzsche wrote to Heinrich von Stein on the beginning of December, 1882.
I would like to understand what he's trying to say here but I have absolutely no clue. Does anyone have any insights? Thanks.

The quotes paragraph can be found on page 197 of "Selected Letters of Friedrich Nietzsche" edited and translated by Christopher Middleton, The University of Chicago Press, 1969.

I think Nietzsche wants to love more perfectly by taking away the heartbreaking and cruel character of human existence. But a tyrant in himself seems to be a partial source of such evil and his inability to love more perfectly! In Batman Soul of The Dragon an Eastern sage instructs Bruce Wayne to imagine the large rock as his enemy and to strike the enemy with his fists. Bruce strikes the rock all night until his fists bleed. The sage comes in the morning, "Even if you break the rock, there will be pebbles, and if you break the pebbles, there will be sand! Bruce, you cannot defeat evil!"

Can you be a bit more specific about what's eluding you here? This passage isn't meant as philosophy; it's a flowery way of commiserating with von Stein on the cruelties and evils of the world, and especially those we inflict on ourselves in the name of… accomplishment or success, maybe? The passage is obviously in reference to some occurrence communicated elsewhere, some sacrifice made for some purpose, and not knowing that makes it more ambiguous.

@TedWrigley - Rational adult opportunity cost does not capture drama wherein the tyrant in us sacrifices and kills the desire to love in its cradle and the sacred lover feels infected with evil. The tyrant in us goes by names such as Satan (Hebrew) - Adversary; Accuser;  the sadistic superego; or the inner critical voice. Early life trauma is the likely origin of distortions. See: Why Does Self-Love Feel Impossible When You Have CPTSD? https://youtu.be/suEEYPSWb3A. Inner child's sacred lover would like to take away from human existence ... its heartbreaking and cruel character.

@SystemTheory: I'm still processing the "Batman Soul of the Dragon" reference…

It sounds like Nietzsche has some intuitive idea of the noble truths whereby desire and attachment leads to suffering.  Or he simply doesn't want anything to have a hold on him despite its appeal.
E.g. from the Pāli Canon, Khaya Sutta (Ending)

From the abandoning of craving [desire], action [kamma] is abandoned. From the
abandoning of action, stress [suffering] is abandoned.
Thus, Udāyin, from the ending of craving comes the ending of action;
from the ending of action, the ending of stress.

Nietzsche is evidently aware of this, e.g. Will to Power 155

In Buddhism this thought prevails: "All passions, everything which
creates emotions and leads to blood, is a call to action"—to this
extent alone are its believers warned against evil.

